# How mail works in WordPress using contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using the contact form 7 plugin in wordpress. When i click on send button at that time mail should be send to user. but i don't no how this works? When I click on send button what happens?
Please explain, i am totally new in WordPress.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

update the contact form config in admin http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/screenshots/

from or mail sections settings show in mention screenshots

Comment: hello@nanchi lal saini  i have changed . but where is mail function in folder structure?

Comment: you just change the settings using wp-admin panel for you active contact form